# PHP: Display associative array with proper index

Tags: php, arrays

I've done a basic SQL query and then a WHILE loop in PHP to loop through them. I've roughly built what I want but the output isn't 100%

I'm close but not close enough. Any guidance on my actual output vs. desired?

All code snippets below.

I have got close with the following *but* it creates a new entry for each record rather than grouping them

```
$a["name"]["contacts"][] = array("name"=>$row["contact"],"address"=>$row["address_1"],"phone"=>array("type"=>$row["type"],"number"=>$row["number"]));
```

**NOTES**

A query can return one or many rows (contacts). Each contact could have multiple phone numbers against them (or just one). Hopefully this is obvious from the data below. I can't do this in SQL as I can only perform very simple SQL statements and no functions.

**DATA FOR BELOW**

```
Contact | Address_1 | Type              | Number
-------------------------------------------------
Barry   |           | Home Mobile Phone | 666
Barry   |           | Home Phone        | 888
Joanne  |           | Home Mobile Phone | 987654
Joanne  |           | Home Phone        | 123456
```

**PHP**

```
$res = RNCPHP\ROQL::query( "SELECT * FROM resource.contact_emergency WHERE collar = '".$row."'" )->next();
$a = Array();

while($row = $res->next()) {
    $a[$row["contact"]]["address"] = $row["address_1"]; 
    $a[$row["contact"]]["phone"][] = array("type"=>$row["type"],"number"=>$row["number"]);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [Barry] => Array
        (
            [address] => 
            [phone] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Home Mobile Phone
                            [number] => 666
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Home Phone
                            [number] => 888
                        )

                )

        )

    [Joanne] => Array
        (
            [address] => 
            [phone] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Home Mobile Phone
                            [number] => 987654
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Home Phone
                            [number] => 123456
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [person] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Barry
                [address] => 
                [phone] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => Home Mobile Phone
                                [number] => 666
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => Home Phone
                                [number] => 888
                            )

                    )
            )

        )

        (
            [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Joanne
                [address] => 
                [phone] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => Home Mobile Phone
                                [number] => 987654
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => Home Phone
                                [number] => 123456
                            )

                    )
            )
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the name to each associative array and then call array_values to convert $a into a simple array:

```
while($row = $res->next()) {
    $a[$row["contact"]]["name"] = $row["contact"]; 
    $a[$row["contact"]]["address"] = $row["address_1"]; 
    $a[$row["contact"]]["phone"][] = array("type"=>$row["type"],"number"=>$row["number"]);
}

$b['person'] = array_values($a);
```